# Eloquent laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the result of the query to the model doing it this way

```
$idDocumento = $_GET['idDocumento'];
$compra = \App\Compra::All()->where('DocumentoImportacion_idDocumentoImportacion', "=", $idDocumento);
```

But data does not bring me even knowing that normally generates mysql query dat, I do not know if it's the right way to do

print this

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
[items:protected] => Array
    (

    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this: `$compra = \App\Compra::All()->where('DocumentoImportacion_idDocumentoImportacion', "=", $idDocumento);`

To:

```
$compra = \App\Compra::where('DocumentoImportacion_idDocumentoImportacion', "=", $idDocumento)->get();
```